# JWT tokens and CSRF token not being sent properly in my requests

Tags: java, spring-boot, jwt, cors, csrf

I am working on an application using a front-end built with Angular and a back-end built with Spring Boot. I am using JSON Web Tokens (JWT) and CSRF tokens for authentication and security, but I am facing issues in sending these tokens properly with my requests.

I'm actually running everything in local.

I checked with the debugger and my csrfTokenHeader is always null, no matter what i do, besides that, the token is saved in the database, and is correctly generated, could this be a header problem ? I'm so lost.

To add more precision to this, i'm sending a POST request with my server, which needs the CSRF token since i'm using the local storage, and one csrf token is properly created while the user is logged in and registering.

Here is the relevant part of my User object that stores the tokens. This object is stored in the local storage:

```
{
  "csrf": "5230a8bf-2e29-41c5-a904-4c51846aaf6e",
  "refreshToken": "the-refresh",
  "token": "the-token"
}
```

However, while sending requests to the server, the CSRF token and the JWTs are not being sent properly in the headers. I am not seeing any issues with the database either.

Here is my CORS configuration:

```
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }
}
```

The tokens are stored properly in the User object and are linked correctly. Moreover, the CORS configuration seems to be set up correctly according to the application's URL.

I have verified the frontend is setting the headers properly, the server side application is configured to accept these headers, and CORS preflight requests are being handled correctly. There don't seem to be any issues with HTTP interceptors, and there are no error messages related to CORS or tokens in the browser console/network logs or server logs.

Could anyone provide insights into what might be the problem and how to solve it?

Also, here are the classes that handle my logic and my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "_csrf_token")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CsrfToken {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "UUID")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="UUID", sequenceName = "sequence_csrf_token", allocationSize = 1)
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "UUID",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator"
    )
    @Column(name = "id_csrf_token", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_user", nullable = false)
    private Users user;

    @Column(name = "csrf_token", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String csrfToken;

    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    private Instant createdAt;

    @Column(name = "expiration_time", nullable = false)
    private Instant expirationTime;

    @Column(name = "csrf_token_expired", nullable = false)
    private boolean csrfTokenExpired;

    @Column(name = "csrf_token_revoked", nullable = false)
    private boolean csrfTokenRevoked;
}
```

TokenService :

```
@Service
public class TokenService {
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    private final CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public TokenService(@Lazy TokenRepository tokenRepository, @Lazy CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository, UserMapper userMapper, @Lazy UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.tokenRepository = tokenRepository;
        this.csrfTokenRepository = csrfTokenRepository;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

        public Token getToken(String login) {
        List<Token> tokens = tokenRepository.findAllValidTokensByUserLogin(login);
        return tokens.isEmpty() ? null : tokens.get(0);
    }
    public String generateCsrfToken(UserDTO userDTO) {
        if (userDTO == null || userDTO.getLogin() == null) {
            throw new InvalidUserException("UserDTO or UserDTO login is null");
        }
        Users user = userMapper.toUserEntity(userDTO);
        if (user == null || user.getLogin() == null) {
            throw new InvalidUserException("User or User login is null");
        }
        List<CsrfToken> csrfTokenList = csrfTokenRepository.findAllByUserAndCsrfTokenRevokedFalseAndCsrfTokenExpiredFalse(user);
        if (!csrfTokenList.isEmpty()) {
            csrfTokenList.forEach(csrfToken -> {
                csrfToken.setCsrfTokenRevoked(true);
                csrfToken.setCsrfTokenExpired(true);
            });
        }
        csrfTokenRepository.saveAll(csrfTokenList);
        csrfTokenList = csrfTokenRepository.findAllByUserAndCsrfTokenRevokedFalseAndCsrfTokenExpiredFalse(user);
        if (!csrfTokenList.isEmpty()) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException("Non-expired, non-revoked CSRF token already exists for the user");
        }
        String csrfToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        CsrfToken tokenEntity = new CsrfToken();

        tokenEntity.setCsrfToken(csrfToken);
        tokenEntity.setUser(user);
        tokenEntity.setCreatedAt(Instant.now());
        tokenEntity.setExpirationTime(Instant.now().plus(Duration.ofMinutes(30)));
        tokenEntity.setCsrfTokenExpired(false);
        tokenEntity.setCsrfTokenRevoked(false);
        csrfTokenRepository.save(tokenEntity);
        return csrfToken;
    }

    public boolean validateCsrfToken(String csrfToken, String userLogin) {
        if (csrfToken == null || userLogin == null) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException("CSRF token or user login is null");
        }
        Users user = userRepository.findByLogin(userLogin).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User not found"));
        List<CsrfToken> csrfTokenList = csrfTokenRepository.findAllByUserAndCsrfTokenRevokedFalseAndCsrfTokenExpiredFalse(user);
        if (csrfTokenList.isEmpty()) {
            return false;
        }

        CsrfToken userToken = csrfTokenList.stream()
                .filter(token -> token.getCsrfToken().equals(csrfToken) && !hasTokenExpired(token))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidCsrfTokenException("Invalid CSRF token"));

        invalidateCsrfToken(csrfToken, userLogin);
        return true;
    }

    public void invalidateCsrfToken(String csrfToken, String userLogin) {
        if(csrfToken == null || userLogin == null) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException("CSRF token or User Login cannot be null");
        }

        Users user = userRepository.findByLogin(userLogin)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User not found with login: " + userLogin));

        List<CsrfToken> csrfTokens = csrfTokenRepository.findAllByUserAndCsrfTokenRevokedFalseAndCsrfTokenExpiredFalse(user);

        if(csrfTokens.isEmpty()) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException("No active CSRF token found for user: " + userLogin);
        }

        CsrfToken tokenToInvalidate = csrfTokens.stream()
                .filter(token -> csrfToken.equals(token.getCsrfToken()) && !hasTokenExpired(token))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new InvalidCsrfTokenException("Invalid CSRF Token"));

        tokenToInvalidate.setCsrfTokenRevoked(true);
        csrfTokenRepository.save(tokenToInvalidate);
    }

    public boolean hasTokenExpired(CsrfToken csrfToken) {
        return csrfToken.getExpirationTime().isBefore(Instant.now());
    }

    public void addCsrfTokenToResponse(HttpServletResponse response, String userLogin) {
        if (response == null || userLogin == null) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException("Response or user login is null");
        }
        Users user = userRepository.findByLogin(userLogin).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("User not found"));
        UserDTO userDTO = userMapper.toUserDTO(user);
        String csrfToken = generateCsrfToken(userDTO);
        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", csrfToken);
        System.out.println("CSRF token added to response: " + csrfToken);
        System.out.println("CSRF token added to response: " + response.getHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN"));
        System.out.println("CSRF token added to response: " + response.getHeaderNames());
        System.out.println("test");
    }
```

JwtAuthenticationFilter

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {


    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;
    private final TokenService tokenService;
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,@NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getServletPath().startsWith("/api/v1/auth/authenticate") || request.getServletPath().startsWith("/api/v1/auth/register")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        if (request.getServletPath().contains("/api/v1/auth")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String userLogin;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        userLogin = jwtService.extractLogin(jwt);

        if (userLogin != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(userLogin);
            var isTokenValid = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt)
                    .map(token -> !token.isExpired() && !token.isRevoked())
                    .orElse(false);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails) && isTokenValid) {


                // CSRF token validation
                final String csrfTokenHeader = request.getHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN");
                Token userToken = tokenService.getToken(userLogin);
                System.out.println("This is " + csrfTokenHeader);

                if (userToken == null || !userToken.getToken().equals(csrfTokenHeader)) {
                    throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException("Invalid CSRF Token");
                }
                Token tokenTime = tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt).get();
                tokenTime.setLastUsedAt(LocalDateTime.now());
                tokenRepository.save(tokenTime);
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

JwtService :

```
@Service
public class JwtService {

    @Value("${jwt.secret-key}")
    private String SECRET_KEY;

    @Value("${jwt.expiration}")
    private long jwtEXPIRATION;

    @Value("${jwt.refresh-token.expiration}")
    private long jwtREFRESH_EXPIRATION;

    public String extractLogin(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public String extractTokenFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public String generateToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        return generateToken(Map.of(), userDetails);
    }

    public String generateRefreshToken(UserDetails userDetails) {
        Map<String, Object> extraClaims = new HashMap<>();
        return buildToken(extraClaims, userDetails, jwtREFRESH_EXPIRATION);
    }

    public String generateToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails) {
            return buildToken(extraClaims, userDetails, jwtEXPIRATION);
    }

    private String buildToken(Map<String, Object> extraClaims, UserDetails userDetails, long expiration) {
        final Date now = new Date();
        final Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + expiration);
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(extraClaims)
                .setSubject(userDetails.getUsername())
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(getSignInKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.HS256)
                .compact();
    }

    public boolean isTokenValid(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String login = extractLogin(token);
        return (login.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

    private boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    private Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration); // Claims::getExpiration is a method reference
    }


    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        System.out.println("Token exctact : " + token);
        return Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(getSignInKey())
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(token)
                .getBody();
    }

    private Key getSignInKey() {
        byte keyBytes[] = Decoders.BASE64.decode(SECRET_KEY);
        return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(keyBytes);
    }
}
```

And my error is the following :

```
2023-05-28T20:35:11.158+02:00 ERROR 4952 --- [nio-5757-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.santa.work.exception.crsfTokenExceptions.InvalidCsrfTokenException: Invalid CSRF Token
    at com.santa.work.security.jwtSecurity.JwtAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:68) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.0.3.jar:6.0.3]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.8.jar:6.0.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623) ~[na:na]
```

The error is on this precise line :

`````
                if (userToken == null || !userToken.getToken().equals(csrfTokenHeader)) {
                    throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException("Invalid CSRF Token");
                }
    ````
`````